# What is special about retraction mapping?

Tags: homotopy-theory, retraction

[image]

What is special about the retraction mapping?
Can't we always find such a mapping, namely identity map of $X$.
Then every space $A$ will be a retract of $X$.

EDIT: Do we need retraction to be continuous?

Comment: In almost every topology-related book there is a hidden assumption that every mapping is continuous unless stated different.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The identity map of $X$ only shows that $X$ is a retract of itself. For any proper subspace $A$ of $X$, $1_X$ is not a map from $X$ to $A$.

Comment: Oh, okie i missed the point that $r$ is a map from $X \rightarrow A$. Thanks

Comment: Do we need retraction to be continuous?

Comment: @Human: Yes, it must be continuous.